# Jquery - Loop through each div with a certain class and apply a new class depending on its width

Tags: jquery, loops, navigation, width, each

I'm having trouble some jquery and was wondering if you could help.

I have a menu with a dropdown and would like to change the position of the dropdown depending on which list item it is AND how wide the drop down is, this is what I've got so far...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var subnavWidth = $('.sub-nav-wrapper').width();

if(subnavWidth > 900) {
    $('.sub-nav-wrapper').addClass('two-column-offers');
} else if (subnavWidth > 800) {
    $('.sub-nav-wrapper').addClass('one-column-offers');
} else if(subnavWidth > 600) {
    $('.sub-nav-wrapper').addClass('offers');
} else if(subnavWidth > 500) {
    $('.sub-nav-wrapper').addClass('two-column');
} else if(subnavWidth > 300) {
    $('.sub-nav-wrapper').addClass('one-column');

}
});
```

but only takes into account the first list item in the menu and applies the relevant class to each of the sub navigations. I want it to check the width for each sub navigation not just the first one and then apply the class to that particular sub nav.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/each is what you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('.sub-nav-wrapper').each(function(i,elem) {
        var width = $(this).width();
        if(width > 900) {
            $(elem).addClass('two-column-offers');
        } else if (width > 800) {
            $(elem).addClass('one-column-offers');
        } else if(width > 600) {
            $(elem).addClass('offers');
        } else if(width > 500) {
            $(elem).addClass('two-column');
        } else if(width > 300) {
            $(elem).addClass('one-column');
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: `e` usually stands for an `event` object. I'd use `el` instead to avoid confusion.

Comment: The jQuery docs now tend to use `domEle` in many examples to make sure that people get it, so there obviously is some confusion going on. I always just use `e`, as I know if I'm using the event or an element, but that's just me!

Comment: One problem I've got is that it's applying the correct class but in some instances it applies the 'offers' class as well, do you know why this could be?

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply this to all the menu items, so you want to select them all using each();

```
$('.sub-nav-wrapper').each();
```

You can then do your code for "each" with an anomonus function.

```
$('.sub-nav-wrapper').each(function() {
    // YOUR CODE HERE                                       
}); // End each
```

Use the `$(this)` keyword to run your checks on "each" item.

```
 $('.sub-nav-wrapper').each(function() {
    alert($(this).width()); // for example                                      
 }); // End each
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.sub-nav-wrapper').each(function() {
       var subnavWidth = $(this).width();
   if(subnavWidth > 900) {
      $(this).addClass('two-column-offers');
   } else if (subnavWidth > 800) {
       $(this).addClass('one-column-offers');
   } else if(subnavWidth > 600) {
     $(this).addClass('offers');
   } else if(subnavWidth > 500) {
      $(this).addClass('two-column');
   } else if(subnavWidth > 300) {
      $(this).addClass('one-column');
   }
 });
 });
```